# sciLab euclidean gcd algorithm with the number of steps extra

Tags: scilab

I want to make euclidean algorithm program `pro sciLab`. It must also return the number of steps you need to compute the greatest common divisor. Here is the code:

```
funcprot(0)
function [erg]= Euclid(a,b)
    erg=[0 0];
    count =0 ;
   if( b == 0)
      count=count+1
      ggt = a

       else
      count=count+1
      ggt= Euclid(b, modulo(a, b))        
end
erg(1)(1) = count
erg(1)(2) = ggt
endfunction
```

But here comes an error :

```
-->Euclid(12,10)
 !--error 15 
Submatrix not correctly defined.
at line      33 of function %s_i_s called by :  
at line      13 of function Euclid called by :  
at line      10 of function Euclid
```

What could go wrong there ? Any idea is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without checking the true meaning of your function, there are 2 syntax errors, which causes the problems:
1. indexing a matrix must be done in the form of `erg(i,j)` not `erg(i)(j)`. But in your case since erg is a vector (one row matrix), you can omit the row index, and use only `erg(j)`.
2. in the if structure once ggt is a scalar (has 1 element) and otherwise it is a vector (has 2 elements). If you want to put a value into `erg(2)`, you have to index erg to choose which element to use:

```
function [erg]= Euclid(a,b)
  erg=[0 0];
  count =0 ;
  if( b == 0)
    count=count+1
    ggt = a   //here ggt has 1 element only!
  else
    count=count+1
    ggt= Euclid(b, modulo(a, b))  //here ggt has 2 elements!
  end

  erg(1) = count    //or erg(1,1) if you like
  erg(2) = ggt(1)   //or erg(1,2), and you have to index ggt to choose which element to use
endfunction
```